# How do i do classic actor become and unbecome in typed actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor, akka-typed

I am building an implementation and I would like to switch around behaviours. How do I switch between three behaviours and back? My issues is that I do not know the right way to change the behaviour and then change it back to the main behaviour after processing that message. I have tried this

```
    def answerMachine: Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.setup{ context: ActorContext[Message] =>
    Behaviors.receiveMessage{
      case s@Behave =>
        println("Am told to behave: changing like chameleon")
        EchoMachine(s, Behaviors.same)
      case Back() =>
        println("Now am back")
        Behaviors.same
    }
  }


def EchoMachine(firstMsg: Message, behav:  Behavior[Message]): Behavior[Message] = Behaviors.setup{ context: ActorContext[Message] =>
    Behaviors.receiveMessage {
      case Back() =>
        println("I have changed to EchoMachine..")
        behav
      case Behave =>
        println("I am behaving oo")
        behav
    }
  }


val system = ActorSystem(TypedConvo.answerMachine, "Machine")

system.ref ! Behave
system.ref ! Back()
```

By the time I sent `Back()` I expected `answerMachine` to be the one that get the message but it was EchoMachine even after changing behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `become` in typed actors because a new behaviour is returned every time. In effect `become` is called every time a message is processed, and that is how state is maintained. So the answer to how to "switch between three behaviours" is simply to return which ever behaviour is required at the time.

The problem with the sample code is that returning `Behaviours.same` means "don't change the behaviour". So setting `behav` to `Behaviours.same` means that `EchoMachine` returns `Behaviours.same` which keeps the behaviour as `EchoMachine` rather than going back to `answerMachine`.

Try setting `behav` to `answerMachine`:

```
Behaviors.receiveMessage{
  case s@Behave =>
    println("Am told to behave: changing like chameleon")
    EchoMachine(s, answerMachine)
  case Back() =>
    println("Now am back")
    Behaviors.same
}
```

Now the `EchoMachine` will return `answerMachine` as the new behaviour once the message is processed. Of course if `EchoMachine` always reverts to `answerMachine` it can just return `answerMachine`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense